# prestashop frontend saying This site can’t be reached

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

When I am accessing this [URL](https://ec2-35-154-236-62.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/stylemart/index.php) saying error like  **This site can’t be reached**

I did necessary changes in configuration table in phpmyadmin, htaccess regeneration using seo and setting up urls made permissions to 777 but still can't access frontend  This site can’t be reached

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The message doesn't come from prestashop. It looks like you have a misconfiguration somewhere. It can be the apache/nginx configuration or a firewall blocking the port 80.

You can browse this `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`to find more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed all necessary changes but didn't realized the ssl thing for test url not required, and disabled the option of using ssl in preferences > general settings from admin account, I disabled and tried with http:// it worked...

Comment: What if the admin also gives `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, after product importing with CSV file. Is the SSL setting also adjustable in the database via HeidiSQL?

Edit: I found a UPDATE query here but it doesn't work for me: https://michalzuber.wordpress.com/2017/07/29/how-to-disable-https-ssl-in-prestashop-via-database-sql/